# Next.js Concurrent Config

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, config, react-suspense

I saw online with several answers on how to enable Next.js Experimental Config for React concurrent mode in Next.js 12.

However, It seems that most of them doesn't work in my case. I am using Next.js 13.1.6 and I wonder did this tag get removed. It shows the error: "Type '{ [Variables]: string; }' is not assignable to type 'ExperimentalConfig'." where [Variables] are some string I tested.

My config is as followed:

```
// next.config.js
const { i18n } = require('./next-i18next.config.js')

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    // Some tested item listed here
    reactMode: 'concurrent',
    reactRoot: 'concurrent',
    concurrentFeatures: true,
  },
  concurrentFeatures: true, // This also didn't work
  reactStrictMode: true,
  i18n
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

Comment: I think reactStrictMode: true needs to be in the outer scope of experimental:- reactStrictMode: true,
experimental: {
  reactRoot: 'concurrent',
},

Comment: @ANISHKUMARMOURYA I did have it in my config above.

Comment: Could you try to add this config and see does it work?

Comment: I already had it outside experimental, and it didn't work. As stated.